# Issues with background position in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-position

I have got issues with setting the background image in IE all versions, It works fine in all the other browsers, can anyone assist me with any possible css hack , or any suggestions , Any help or advice will be highly appreciated , thanks, below is the link:
[website](http://sales.b2bleadforce.com/blog/)

Also , on other pages the background image is not repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [validation of your css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://sales.b2bleadforce.com/css/layout.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

> Property background-position-x doesn't exist :  center Property
>
> background-position-y doesn't exist :  200px

change the css on your .page to be something like

```
.page {
  background: url('../images/body-bg.png') no-repeat center 200px;
  top: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

learn more about background css at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background

Comment: also f12 shows the main form element atop your container element, that holds the background-image. i didn't look much past that, but i'll bet that's causing you some problems as well

Comment: did that doesnt make any difference